How to specify the amount to be minted and total supply in "createAndMint(...)"?
Fungible tokens
The createAndMint(...) function accepts the parameter amount. This is an amount of tokens to be minted immediately, right? Then how to specify the total supply?

The total supply is defined as the total number of tokens currently minted, so if amount is the amount of tokens to be minted immediately, then total supply will be that amount.
If you decide to mint more tokens, then the supply will increase.
You can learn more about SPL Token at https://spl.solana.com/token

what if I wanted to specify the total supply greater than the amount of the tokens I wanted to mint right away?

and it's different from how it's in Ethereum, right? 2 distinct numbers

Tokens have to exist in some account, and there's no ability to set a max supply. If you want to mimic that kind of functionality, you can "pre-mint" tokens into some other account, and distribute from there, rather than minting new tokens

and this is different from how it's in Ethereum, right?

Yes, ERC-20 is an interface, whereas SPL Token is a specific implementation. So your Ethereum contract can do whatever it wants, but your SPL Token is constrained by how the SPL Token program operates

You've deliberately answered a different question
